# How to fix "variable used in lambda expression should be final"?

Tags: java, lambda, rx-java2

I'm making an android app and trying to either add a Map Marker to a map if it's the first api call or just re-set the position of the marker. I'm using RxJava2 for repeated calls to the API. The problem is I cannot check if it's the first API call as I'm not allowed to access the non-final boolean.

```
boolean firstReposition = true;
        //Create position call
        ISSPositionService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(ISSPositionService.class);

        //create observable
        Observable<ISSPositionData> issPositionCall = service.getPosition();

        Disposable disposable = issPositionCall.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delay(30, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(positionData -> {
                    LatLng currentIssPosition = new LatLng(positionData.getIssPosition().getLatitude(), positionData.getIssPosition().getLongitude());
                    if (firstReposition) {
                        issMarkerOptions.position(currentIssPosition);
                        map.addMarker(issMarkerOptions);
                        firstReposition = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        issMarker.setPosition(currentIssPosition);
                    }

                    //animate camera so it shows current position
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentIssPosition));
                });
```

How would I rewrite the code so I'm able to check and set the boolean?

Comment: Isn't this when you use an [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html)?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson doesn't seem to work...

Comment: declared two places `boolean firstReposition = true;` why? what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Deadpool Oops sorry, my mistake, just tried something out and forgot to take it out, edited the question accordingly

Comment: `AutomicBoolean` set should work right? @AlexGogl

Comment: To clarify, you should declare your AtomicBoolean as final

Comment: Ahh yes, got it, thank you! @Deadpool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AtomicBoolean`, you can use `set()` and `get()` methods [java-docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html)

```
AtomicBoolean firstReposition = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    //Create position call
    ISSPositionService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(ISSPositionService.class);

    //create observable
    Observable<ISSPositionData> issPositionCall = service.getPosition();

    Disposable disposable = issPositionCall.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delay(30, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(positionData -> {
                LatLng currentIssPosition = new LatLng(positionData.getIssPosition().getLatitude(), positionData.getIssPosition().getLongitude());
                if (firstReposition) {
                    issMarkerOptions.position(currentIssPosition);
                    map.addMarker(issMarkerOptions);
                    firstReposition.set(false);
                }
                else {
                    issMarker.setPosition(currentIssPosition);
                }

                //animate camera so it shows current position
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentIssPosition));
            });
```